# How do I add lists or ListT to this monad transformer?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I have a game record that represents the current state of a game.

```
data Game = Game { score :: Int, turn :: Int }
```

I want to be able to create a bunch of functions to change the game state, and also use a random number generator as well as keep a log of what happened to get from one state to another. So I created a `GameState` record that contains the additional information.

```
type History = [String]
data GameState = GameState Game StdGen History
```

Now I want to create a data type for the functions that are going to be acting on this `GameState`. They'll be modeled imperatively as updates to the game as well as rolling dice and logging what's happening. So I created a monad transformer of all the effects I want.

```
type Effect = WriterT History (RandT StdGen (State Game))
```

Writing the function to run an `Effect` on a given `GameState` is pretty simple.

```
runEffect :: GameState -> Effect () -> GameState
runEffect (GameState game stdGen history) effect =
  let ((((), newHist), newGen), newGame) =
        runState (runRandT (runWriterT effect) stdGen) game
  in GameState newGame newGen newHist
```

Perfect. Now I want to model one additional thing. Some `Effects` can have multiple different resulting `GameStates`. So my `runEffect` should actually return a `[GameState]`. I need to add `ListT` to this monad transformer, probably. And then all of my `Effects` will have the option of producing more than one result if need be. But also if they are just a one-to-one mapping then then can act like that too.

I tried to make the following changes:

```
type Effect2 = ListT (WriterT [String] (RandT StdGen (State Game)))

runEffect2 :: GameState -> Effect2 a -> [GameState]
runEffect2 (GameState game stdGen history) effect =
  let l = runListT effect
      result = map (\e->runState (runRandT (runWriterT e) stdGen) game) l
  in map (\((((), newHist), newGen), newGame)->
           GameState newGame newGen newHist)
         result
```

What I'm trying to do is add `ListT` to the transformer, outside of the `Writer` and `Random` and `State` because I want for the different branches of the computation to have different histories and independent states and random generators. But this doesn't work. I get the following type error.

```
Prelude λ: :reload [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( redux.hs, interpreted )

redux.hs:31:73: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[WriterT
                                       w
                                       (RandT StdGen (StateT Game Data.Functor.Identity.Identity))
                                       a1]’
                  with actual type ‘WriterT [String] (RandT StdGen (State Game)) [a]’
    • In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘l’
      In the expression:
        map (\ e -> runState (runRandT (runWriterT e) stdGen) game) l
      In an equation for ‘result’:
          result
            = map (\ e -> runState (runRandT (runWriterT e) stdGen) game) l
    • Relevant bindings include
        result :: [(((a1, w), StdGen), Game)] (bound at redux.hs:31:7)
        l :: WriterT [String] (RandT StdGen (State Game)) [a]
          (bound at redux.hs:30:7)
        effect :: Effect2 a (bound at redux.hs:29:44)
        runEffect2 :: GameState -> Effect2 a -> [GameState]
          (bound at redux.hs:29:1) 
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I effectively want to be able to expand one `GameState` into multiple `GameStates`. Each with an independent `StdGen` and `History` for that branch. I have done this by putting everything into the `Game` record and just using non-monadic functions for the effects. This works and it's pretty straight forward. However, composition of these functions is really annoying because they're acting like state and I need to need to handle it myself. This is what monads are great at so I figured reusing that here would be wise. Sadly the list aspect of it has me really confused.

Comment: Are you actually using `Effect2` in `runEffect2`? The signature says `Effect`.

Comment: That was just an error in copying it over. In the file I have, I have both versions together with different names. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the immediate cause of the error is that the type of `runListT` is...

```
GHCi> :t runListT
runListT :: ListT m a -> m [a]
```

... but you are using it as if it produced a `[m a]`, rather than a `m [a]`. In other words, the `map` in the definition of `result` shouldn't be there.

Secondly, in a monadic stack the inner monads rule over the outer ones. Wrapping, for instance, `StateT` with `ListT` results in a garden-variety stateful computation that happens to produce multiple results. We can see that by specialising the type of `runListT`:

```
GHCi> :set -XTypeApplications
GHCi> :t runListT @(StateT _ _)
runListT @(StateT _ _) :: ListT (StateT t t1) a -> StateT t t1 [a]
```

Wrapping `ListT` with `StateT`, on the other hand, gives us a computation that produces multiple states as well as results:

```
GHCi> :t runStateT @_ @(ListT _)
runStateT @_ @(ListT _)
  :: StateT t (ListT t1) a -> t -> ListT t1 (a, t)
```

That being so, you want to swap the transformers in your stack. If you want to have multiple effects for everything, as you describe, and you don't need `IO` as your base monad, you don't need `ListT` at all -- simply put `[]` at the bottom of the stack.

Thirdly, on a tangential note, avoid the `ListT` from *transformers*. It is known to be unlawful, and it has been deprecated [in the latest version of *transformers*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-List.html). A simple replacement for it is provided by the [*list-t* package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-t-1/docs/ListT.html). (If, at some point further down the road, you get to make use of the *pipes* streaming library, you might also find [its own version of `ListT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.2/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html#g:6) useful.)